# How to fake a network path?

Tags: windows, path

If possible, I would like to make a network folder of my choosing to listen to `\\Albert-pc\Templates\`. The computer `Albert-pc` doesn't exist anymore. How can I make a "fake" network path `\\Albert-pc\Templates`? Preferably on the Windows server, but a local redirect is also just fine.

Underlying problem: Many MS Word files are attached to an old network template like `\\Albert-pc\Templates\Fax.dot` while both path and template do not exist anymore and when I open such Word file it takes really minutes to open. If the path exists, then Word opens just as quickly as normal, whether the template it refers to is present or not (this I have tested).

Comment: In my case I was able to do but doing some modifications on the machine registry.
See instructions here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/23823/how-to-configure-a-windows-machine-to-allow-file-sharing-with-a-dns-alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping the unc path is easy.. `net use` it's getting it to match for Albert-Pc which is hard.

What about your hosts file, Cant your just throw albert-pc in there or name your pc Albert-pc?

You could also setup a loopback adapter and then put albert-pc as the address of that. it would be easier than faking the protocols required to do this.

The only other way is to make a UNC / SMB listener which responds to Albert/PC and gives you really the files in any directory you want from where you want them.

You can also setup an alias to your machine as Albert-PC or you can setup a VM and map to the vm...

Comment: I think mapping Albert-Pc to a loop back would do it for you and that is an answer :) and better then unc path faking which is not going to be possible without the hosts entry / loopback anyway IMHO.

Comment: Relax. How can I give my server an alias? A loopback adapter, is that hardware? No, I cannot rename any other pc Albert-pc.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/46576/can-a-server-have-two-names

Comment: Loopback adapter -> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708341(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: +1 for the effort and accepted because I trust a server alias will work. Solved it [like this](http://superuser.com/questions/159054/remove-custom-template-from-word-2003#comment641086_159054) though.