# create a dummy network location

Tags: network-shares, path, network-drive, network-location

I am mentaining an application that ,when I try to run, gives an error message : "You must have a Drive M:\, mapped to Path="\some\network\path" " .... so I wnt to simulate that this path exists in order to run the application -the path is only somewhere to throw output files to- .... I don't currently know where the configurations are to edit the path and I just want to simulate that it exists .... I thought I can create a virtual machine that contains this path but very costy .... any other suggestions?

Comment: See here: [How to fake a network path](http://superuser.com/questions/530346/how-to-fake-a-network-path).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You must have a Drive M:\, mapped to Path="\some\network\path"

> the path is only somewhere to throw output files to

You can use `subst` to map `M:` to a directory of your choice, for example `c:\temp`:

```
subst M: C:\temp
```

To remove the `subst` later:

```
subst M: /D
```

Example:

```
F:\test>subst m: c:\temp

F:\test>dir m:
 Volume in drive M has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C8D0-DF1E

 Directory of M:\

01/05/2016  22:48    <DIR>          .
01/05/2016  22:48    <DIR>          ..
21/04/2016  22:43    <DIR>          acrord32_sbx
14/07/2015  11:01                 0 FXSAPIDebugLogFile.txt
30/04/2016  10:08           262,144 ICACHE-04044202.tmp
30/04/2016  10:08           262,144 ICACHE-14B5B6BB.tmp
30/04/2016  10:08           262,144 ICACHE-19EE2C4D.tmp
30/04/2016  10:08           262,144 ICACHE-55F8C5A0.tmp
30/04/2016  10:08           262,144 ILIST-00000000.tmp
30/04/2016  10:08           262,144 ILIST-22EF1586.tmp
30/04/2016  10:08           262,144 ILIST-28CAE025.tmp
30/04/2016  10:08           262,144 ILIST-6E36D60E.tmp
28/04/2016  21:36    <DIR>          mozilla-temp-files
19/03/2016  00:36           192,512 sfamcc00001.dll
19/03/2016  00:36           158,720 sfareca00001.dll
01/05/2016  10:29            16,384 ~DF691E2F90109AA7E3.TMP
              12 File(s)      2,464,768 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  72,210,866,176 bytes free

F:\test>subst m: /d
```

---

#### `subst` usage

```
F:\test>subst /?
Associates a path with a drive letter.

SUBST [drive1: [drive2:]path]
SUBST drive1: /D

  drive1:        Specifies a virtual drive to which you want to assign a path.
  [drive2:]path  Specifies a physical drive and path you want to assign to
                 a virtual drive.
  /D             Deletes a substituted (virtual) drive.

Type SUBST with no parameters to display a list of current virtual drives.

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [subst](http://ss64.com/nt/subst.html) - Substitute a drive letter for a network or local path.

Comment: I tried it with the network path it didn't work .... may be I am doing soething wrong:
subst \\some\network\location M:
Invalid parameter \\some\network\location

Comment: The whole point is to use something **other** than the network path to simulate it. If `m:` is defined then you don't need the network path as a target for dumping files. That's why I suggested `c:\temp`.

Comment: aha .... got it